# How to call a Getter from a Class with Vaadins @Route Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I want to access a getter from a Class that uses Vaadins @Route annotation.

Instantiating the class does not work and autowiring neither
This is my entry point. From here Id like to call the getter from the button in the next class to add the actionlistener(clicklistener) to further utilize its data in a small swing window

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{

    @Autowired
    Main main;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = builder.run(args);
        View view = new View();
    }
}
```

This is the class which implements Vaadin. Here is the getter I want to call

```
@Route("index")
public class Main extends VerticalLayout {
    VerticalLayout buttons = new VerticalLayout();
    TextField field = new TextField();
    Button button = new Button("commit change");

    public Main() {
        button.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(field.getValue())) {
                Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox(field.getValue());
                buttons.add(checkbox);
                field.setValue("");
            }
        });


        add(
                new H1("Control it!"),
                buttons,
                field,
                button

        );

    }

    public TextField getField() {
        return field;
    }
```

Comment: This cannot work because things in the `App` class only happen once during server startup whereas there will be multiple instance of `Main`; one for every browser window or tab that has the application opened. There are various ways to still let the two classes interact with each other, but which approach to use depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get the button, so I can add the Mouseclicklistener in my controller which has the methods to deal with the changes I want to have on the Swing UI. So the Swing UI should react dynamicly on button presses.

Comment: Without knowing any other constraints, I would then recommend exactly the approach that you mentioned in your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to avoid calling the getters

I made the Gui Application that should get data from the Vaadin a @Component too and @Autowired it into Main. This might be the wrong way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can autowire in the `Main` class, if you want to use it as a bean you need to add the Spring `@Component` (or Vaadin's `@SpringComponent`) annotation, as well as `@UIScope` for it to return the right instance of the bean.

Comment: I tried annotating the Main Class with "@Route()", "@SpringComponent" and "@UIScope", but all I get is a NPE